# Use Regular Expression to find text within a pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

Can a Regular Expression find the text within a pattern and allow me to replace the non found text with PowerShell?
So I have this issue where many AssemblyInfo.CS are different across 100+ projects:

- AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © My Company Full Name Ltd 2016")]
- AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2016")]
- AssemblyCopyright("© 2016")]

Is it possible for it to find AssemblyCopyright("")] and then allow me to insert my own text to where the other text was, even if the text is different within the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
AssemblyCopyright\(".*"\)\]
```

And replace with the string of your choice:

```
AssemblyCopyright("The string of your choice")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell regex might be disturbing because of multiple way to deal with escape characters :

So as you nested your string beetween simple quote :

- Groups can be marked with bracket or not : (.n) or .n
- Double quotes can be considered as standard characters
- Brackets can be considered as standard characters

If you nested your string beetween double quote, the double quote inside the string must be escape with standard powershell escape character : `"

So all following examples return the same result

```
$pattern = 'AssemblyCopyright("what ever in there")]'

# standard regex
$pattern -replace 'AssemblyCopyright\(\"(.*)\"\)\]', 'AssemblyCopyright("new pattern")]'
# no quote escape
$pattern -replace 'AssemblyCopyright\("(.*)"\)\]', 'AssemblyCopyright("new pattern")]'
# no brackets escape
$pattern -replace 'AssemblyCopyright\("(.*)"\)]', 'AssemblyCopyright("new pattern")]'
# no parenthesis to define group
$pattern -replace 'AssemblyCopyright\(".*"\)]', 'AssemblyCopyright("new pattern")]'
# double quote instead of simple quote
$pattern -replace "AssemblyCopyright\(`".*`"\)]", "AssemblyCopyright(`"new pattern`")]"
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with more advanced regular-expression techniques:

```powershell
> 'AssemblyCopyright("foo bar")]' -replace '(?<=AssemblyCopyright\(")[^"]*', 'bar'
AssemblyCopyright("bar")]
```

- `(?<=AssemblyCopyright\(")` is a lookbehind assertion that matches the specified subexpression, but doesn't make it part of the match (what is *captured* and, in this case, *replaced*).
- Since the lookbehind assertion found everything up to and including the opening `"` of the attribute, all we need is to match up to but excluding the next `"` (`[^"]*`) to fully match only the *contents* of the double-quoted string (the attribute value).
- Thus, we only need to specify the attribute *value* as the replacement string (sans quoting).